# Update MySQL table on a jQuery event

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a timer that counts down from 1 hour to zero. When it reaches zero, jQuery fires an event (code below).

I need a database table to be updated to a -1 of what it currently is. (So for example if the numerical value of the table is set to 20, after the countdown reaches zero, it becomes 19 and so on).

My question is - how do I update a MySQL database in this way based on the jQuery function? I have tried using PHP, but it updates the table instantly, not when the countdown reaches zero. (I've tried searching this aftewards, and I'm realizing now that PHP is server side, and jQuery is client side, but I still don't know how to make something like this work).

Thanks very much for all your help!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">



var year=2012;        //Set initial values for timer
var month=06;          
var day=16;           
var hour=17;          
var minute=10;        
var tz=+12;            


var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min){
    theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min;
    var today=new Date();
    var todayy=today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000) {
    todayy+=1900; }
    var todaym=today.getMonth();
    var todayd=today.getDate();
    var todayh=today.getHours();
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
    var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60);
    var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);
    var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));
    var dd=futurestring-todaystring;
  //  var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
    var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
    var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
    if(dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){

      //--TIMER REACHES ZERO HERE. Code needed to update MySQL would go here?

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('count2').style.display="none";
      // document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML=dday;
        document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML=dhour;
        document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML=dmin;
        document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML=dsec;
        setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

PS. This is the PHP code I tried using to update my database table:

```
<?php
        include("db.php");
        mysql_select_db("myData") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE cards SET buy=0.01 WHERE id='67'") or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
```

Comment: You can pass the data to PHP by having the javascript submit a form, jQuery .ajax(), etc. However that PHP script isn't going to do you much good because every time it's run (assuming it gets a db connection) it's just going to set the table cards.buy equal to 0.01 on the row with id 67 (if that exists)...

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use $.ajax ([http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/][1]) to do it because jQuery alone do not have access to the database on the server.
In your javascript code inside the if :     

if(dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){

      //--TIMER REACHES ZERO HERE. Code needed to update MySQL would go here?

      $.ajax({ 
          url: "pathToYourPHPUpdateScript.php",
          type: "POST",
          success: function(){
            alert("MYSQL UPDATED!");
          }
      });

    }
```